# Select when not all sub-objects have the selector field

Tags: json, key, jq

Using this example:

```json
{
  "node1": {
    "name": "host001",
    "free": true
  },
  "node2": {
    "name": "host002",
    "free": false
  },
  "node3": {
    "name": "host003",
    "free": false
  },
  "node4": {
    "name": "host004",
    "free": true
  }
}
```

I can retrieve the node names where "free" = true with:

```
.[]|select(.free == true).name
```

https://jqplay.org/s/vmQFs8KYF2Q

But my JSON has some elements without this "free" key:

```json
{
  "id": "foo",
  "node1": {
    "name": "host001",
    "free": true
  },
  "node2": {
    "name": "host002",
    "free": false
  },
  "node3": {
    "name": "host003",
    "free": false
  },
  "node4": {
    "name": "host004",
    "free": true
  }
}
```

Then my commands fails with `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 4`

I think the solution lies somehow in "has(free)", but can't find the right syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `.id` (a string in this case) has no fields (only objects do), so trying to evaluate `.free` on it will fail.

You could catch the failing evaluation with a `try`/`catch` [expression](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#try-catch). Use `try` on `.free`, and `empty` as the exception handler, as you probably only want it to silently output nothing in that case. With the `empty` [builtin](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#empty), you simply make it run out of input contexts, thus break out of this iteration step altogether with no further evaluation.

```bash
.[] | select((try .free catch empty) == true).name
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=.%5B%5D%20%7C%20select%28%28try%20.free%20catch%20empty%29%20%3D%3D%20true%29.name&j=%7B%0A%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%0A%20%20%22node1%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host001%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20true%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node2%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host002%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20false%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node3%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host003%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20false%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node4%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host004%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20true%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

However, `empty` is already the default exception handler, so you can just omit it and only use `try .free`:

```bash
.[] | select((try .free) == true).name
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=.%5B%5D%20%7C%20select%28%28try%20.free%29%20%3D%3D%20true%29.name&j=%7B%0A%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%0A%20%20%22node1%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host001%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20true%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node2%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host002%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20false%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node3%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host003%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20false%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node4%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host004%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20true%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Alternatively, you could also use the [error suppression operator](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#error-suppression-optional-operator) `?` on `.free` which is a shortcut to `try .free`:

```bash
.[] | select(.free? == true).name
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=.%5B%5D%20%7C%20select%28.free%3F%20%3D%3D%20true%29.name&j=%7B%0A%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%0A%20%20%22node1%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host001%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20true%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node2%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host002%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20false%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node3%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host003%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20false%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node4%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host004%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20true%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Lastly, the result of checking if a boolean value is `true` is the same as that boolean value itself, so the shortest way would probably be:

```bash
.[] | select(.free?).name
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=.%5B%5D%20%7C%20select%28.free%3F%29.name&j=%7B%0A%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%0A%20%20%22node1%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host001%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20true%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node2%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host002%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20false%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node3%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host003%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20false%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node4%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host004%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20true%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

---

Your idea of using `has` is good, but it would, again, only work on objects (and `null`), and therefore fail just the same on other types (like the string under `.id`). But you can, instead, directly check the type of the context using the `type` [filter](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#type):

```bash
.[] | select(type == "object" and .free == true).name
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=.%5B%5D%20%7C%20select%28type%20%3D%3D%20%22object%22%20and%20.free%20%3D%3D%20true%29.name&j=%7B%0A%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%0A%20%20%22node1%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host001%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20true%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node2%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host002%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20false%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node3%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host003%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20false%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node4%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host004%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20true%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Or use the `objects` [shortcut](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#arrays-objects-iterables-booleans-numbers-normals-finites-strings-nulls-values-scalars) which automatically selects objects only:

```bash
.[] | select(objects.free == true).name
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=.%5B%5D%20%7C%20select%28objects.free%20%3D%3D%20true%29.name&j=%7B%0A%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%0A%20%20%22node1%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host001%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20true%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node2%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host002%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20false%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node3%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host003%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20false%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node4%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host004%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20true%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

And, here as well, there's no need for checking a boolean's equality to `true`:

```bash
.[] | select(objects.free).name
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=.%5B%5D%20%7C%20select%28objects.free%29.name&j=%7B%0A%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%0A%20%20%22node1%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host001%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20true%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node2%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host002%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20false%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node3%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host003%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20false%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22node4%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22host004%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22free%22%3A%20true%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: OK, thank you for all those details.
I've just noticed that now, I only need to retrieve the 1st found element. I tried to add a "first", or [0], but it's KO. What's the right syntax please ?

Comment: @Burps Use `first/1` on the whole filter, so `first(.[] | select(…).name)` should do.

Comment: thank you @pmf, Now I get exactly what I want.